# Name for the class of functions of the form $f:A^N\to A$

Tags: reference-request

Let $A$ be some space and $N$ be an integer. Does a function of the form $f:A^N\to A$ have a particular name? I'm looking for a keyword to see if there are any general properties of functions of this type.

Comment: That depends, is $A$ a space of scalars, or any space?

Comment: Usually it's $f:N\rightarrow A^N \rightarrow A$ and it's called evaluation, i.e. normal function call in any programming language.

Comment: @R.Burton Any space will do

Comment: $N$-ary operator?  (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity.)

Comment: @jonem I'm not sure then. If $A$ is a scalar space, then $f$ belongs to the class of scalar functions (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ScalarFunction.html). But if $f$ is tensor-valued, then it could be almost anything. You could consider $f$ to be the class of all possible index/dimension reductions (of which tensor contraction would be a special case). But you would have to allow the Cartesian product of two $n$-dimensional objects to yield an $n^2$-dimensional object (i.e. the vector $((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2))$ is equivalent to the matrix $\left(\begin{matrix}x_1&x_2\\y_1&y_2\end{matrix}\right)$).

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is an **operation** on the set $A$ of arity $N.$ More specifically, a finitary operation.

Of course "operation" has many meanings, but this meaning is certainly common particularly when discussing algebraic theories in general. For example it is used in Grätzer's *Universal Algebra*, a standard reference.